Consequences of starting a new relaxation calculation from the final coordinates of an interrupted run
In order to address oscillating total force during an ongoing relaxation calculation in Quantum ESPRESSO, I've found it effective to interrupt the current run and commence a new relaxation calculation from scratch using the final relaxed coordinates. Therefore, I'm interested to know if this approach is considered a good practice, and what potential consequences it might entail?

if referring to atomic and cell optimisation,  where algorithm fluctuate very close to minima. It is good to restart or change algorithm if possible

@Pranav kumar  okay,what i am referring to here is optimization of atomic positions.  Will there be any bad consequences for this practice ?

if energy/atom difference between last scf of interrupted run and new calculation is very small then we reach same local minima. There is no bad consequences of such practice as long scf cycle is well converged.
